# Guest network connected to internet fine, but primary network did not work

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

Hope the expert here can help me.
I tried to connect to my primary network it, it indicated as connected, whether i try to go to any website , a little "!" will appear next to the signal bars.

When connect using LAN cable it worked fine. Or connecting wirelessly to a guest network it worked fine too.

I tried disable the IPv6...doesn't work
I tried manually updating my IP and DNS doesn't work
Tried using goggle DNS i.e. 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4 doesn't work
I tried reset router ....problem exist.

One thing i am sure of is my Andriod devices connected fine to the primary network.

Any help please . thanks

Comment: What IP and what DNS does the PC receive? Can you ping the gateway (i.e. the router)? Can you try a tracert to 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Usually i can't get connected, If i do "Rarely" get connected I do have a IP address. i tried tracert to google.com ...i got a message saying "unable to resolve target system name google.com"

Comment: When you DO get an IP does it always work? And viceversa? What DNS servers do you get `ipconfig /all`?

Answer (score 1):

I would comment instead of answer but I don't have enough rep yet.  Is it possible you are missing the default gateway in your router for the non-guest network?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using windows?  Is the primary network a home network?

Are you ablet to actually connect to the WiFi?  Are you getting an IP address?  Are you using DHCP?

Can you ping your router?

A little more information would be helpful.

Comment: Yes i am using windows7 . yes the primary net work is home network.    I cannot connect via WiFi, that means i am not getting a IP. Yes i am using DHCP. Even if i managed to get connected i do have a IP. but i can't surf the net.